# Getting the error type mismatch while using functions in scala

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SparkSession, DataFrame}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

object sparkcpp
{

  val spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
  import spark.implicits._
  def extract(): DataFrame =
    {
      val df = spark.read.option("inferschema","true").option("header","true").csv("olive\\A.csv")
     }
 
  def transform(df: DataFrame): DataFrame =
    {

      val df = df.select(df("name"),df("age"))
    }
  def load(df: DataFrame): DataFrame =
    {
      val df = df.write.csv("testing.csv")
    }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit =
    {
      load(transform(extract()))
    }
}
```

*In the above code i'm getting the 'type mismatch error' when I try to load the dataframe in a csv file

*This is the first time i'm working with scala using function. Am I doing it right?

*The aim of the program is to load the dataframe defined to the specified location using function.

- My major concern is the functions that i've used..is it right? please make changes as required.

[image: sample csv file]

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SparkSession, DataFrame}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

object sparkcpp
{

  val spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
  import spark.implicits._
  def extract(): DataFrame =
    {
       spark.read.option("inferschema","true").option("header","true").csv("olive\\A.csv")
      

     }
 
  def transform(df: DataFrame): DataFrame =
    {

      df.select(df("name"),df("age"))
      
    }
  def load(df: DataFrame): DataFrame =
    {
      df.write.csv("testing.csv")
    }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit =
    {
      load(transform(extract()))
    }
}
```

You should return the dataframe from extract and load method

Comment: i'm getting the type mismatch error in "df.write.csv("testing1.csv")"  says  found   : Unit
required: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

Comment: you can write few lines of code for read , transformation and write. Do you really required  more methods

Comment: object sparkcpp extends App
{

  val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("appname").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
  import spark.implicits._
  
   
  val df = spark.read.option("inferschema","true").option("header","true").csv("olive\\A.csv")
  val result = df.select(df("name"),df("age"))    
result.write.csv("testing.csv")
 
}

Comment: yes the structure goes this way... the main method should write the result in the desired format by load method..Why am I getting type mismatch error?

Comment: main aim of this program is that i should return the dataframe through function only!

Comment: def load(df: DataFrame): Unit =
    {
      df.write.csv("testing.csv")
    }

Comment: change DF to Unit in load method

Comment: After changing to unit.. error is not there but load is not happening ...(i.e) no output to the write file

Comment: execute df.show() and verify the dataframe

Comment: Again the type mismatch error happens when I try to verify the dataframe

Comment: can you please share  sample csv file

Comment: I've added the csv file ..could you please check now?